Using year dummies in rqpd command along with individual penalized fixed effects - is this the correct way to control for two-way FEs?
I am working with the following code:
library(readxl)
library(quantreg)
library(plm)
library(Matrix)
library(MatrixModels)
library(Formula)
library(rqpd)
rqpd_model <- rqpd(lnSPREAD ~ lag(ESG_Composite_,1) + RATING + lag(lnMKTCAP,1) + lag(ROA,1) + lag(ICR,1) + lag(LEV,1) + MATURITY_IN_YEARS + as.factor(t)| as.factor(id), panel(method = "pfe", taus=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.50, 0.6, 0.70, 0.8, 0.9), tauw=rep(1/9, 9)) , data = df.pd, control = quantreg::sfn.control( tmpmax = 50000))
In the code above, I include individual FEs 'as.factor(id)' as penalized fixed effects (as in Koenker,2004). To control for time FEs, I simply add the time dummies as regressors 'as.factor(t)'.
I am confused about whether this is the correct way to control for two-way FEs in panel quantile regression. I am in doubt because the nature of effects is nonadditive in quantile regression - so, does inclusion of dummies correctly control for time FEs as it would in case of OLS regression?
I tried performing panel quantile regression using the rqpd command in R. I want to understand whether inclusion of time dummies correctly control for time FEs in case of quantile regression.
I have a much larger N compared to T.
